# Detrending for a large dataset consisting of many group time-series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, large-data

I have a huge dataset consisting of many individuals (~20000), each with a month of daily data.

I am thinking of detrending those individual time series that are non-stationary but visually inspecting each time series for a trend before detrending them is going to be very time-consuming.

My questions are:

1. Is it appropriate to detrend all the time-series without inspecting them?
2. And what happens if one detrends a time-series that is already stationary?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing trend with stationarity. You can test for both without needing to visually inspect the plots.

For a trend you can simply build a linear model with time as your variable. If time is significant, that is the slope is increasing / decreasing, then there is a trend in your data.

For stationarity you can use a variety of tests, for ex. Ljung-Box, and there are tests which tell you how many differences you have to take for stationarity.

Also, there is such a thing as over-differencing, so you may want to be careful about needlessly differencing a series.

Comment: if the series is 1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5 you will get a false conclusion from your linear model with a trend .